# Finding the limit of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the limit of the following series:
$$ S_n=\frac1{1+a}+\frac1{2(1+2a)}+\frac1{3(1+3a)}+\cdots$$
where $$ a=\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots $$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean to evaluate the limit for a fixed value of $a$?

Comment: @barto Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac1{n(1+na)}=\frac1n-\frac a{1+na}$$

So, for example with $\,a=\frac12\;$

$$\sum_{n=1}^k\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+2}\right)=1-\frac13+\frac12-\frac14+\frac13-\frac15+\frac14-\frac16+\ldots\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\frac32$$

Answer (score 2):

You mean? $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i(1+ia)}$$
Since,
$$\frac{1}{i(1+ia)}=\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+i}$$
So,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i(1+ia)}
=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+i})
=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{1}{a}}{\frac{1}{i}}$$

Comment: Could you explain why does the last equality hold?

Comment: when expand $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+i})$, you will find the items from $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+1}$ would be counteracted.